# Export Multiple LDFLAGS, CPPFLAGS, PKG_CONFIG_PATH in a zshrc File

Tags: zsh, compiling, environment-variables

In my `.zshrc` file I have existing exports for OpenSSL.

```bsh
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Now I have to compile packages that require the `zlib` library. How can I add these flags without overwriting the previous?

I tried chaining them on with a `:` like is done for path, but that didn't seem to work, when I run `./configure` it reading them as a single flag.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib:-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib'

Can someone please advise on how to do this correctly?

Comment: you *really* should not be keeping these LD, CPP, CFLAGS in your .zshrc. They are specific to building *some* software. Set them, typically using the configure/cmake/scons/... infrastructure to build whatever you want to link against your specific openssl.

Answer (score 8):

It's unclear why you set these variables in your shell's startup scripts, or why you need to set them at all as they should be figured out by the `configure` script, possibly using `pkg-config` (so `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` might still be interesting to modify).  I'm ignoring that and will instead be concentrating on how to add to these variables.

---

The `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` variables contains command line flags that are passed to tools at various stages when compiling software.  These should contain space-delimited flags.

```bsh
export LDFLAGS=-L/some/directory
```

Later (note, you only have to `export` a variable once):

```bsh
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/other/directory"
```

Or,

```bsh
LDFLAGS+=" -L/other/directory"
```

The `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable is used by the `pkg-config` tool.  It's manual states (my emphasis):

> `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`
> This can be used to specify **a colon-separated list of paths** to
> search for package files.  If given, this list of paths is
> prepended to the standard search path.

So,

```bsh
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/some/directory
```

Later:

```bsh
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/other/directory
```

Or,

```bsh
PKG_CONFIG_PATH+=:/other/directory
```

Comment: Because they aren't found in the configure script and brew knows this so they advise you to add them. I ended up doing it by adding the previous to the end, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 4):

I turned out to be as simple as adding the pre-existing export to the end.

```bsh
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib:$LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include:$CPPFLAGS"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

No squawking anywhere and all compiled correctly.

Thanks for the answers, much appreciated.

Comment: LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS are separated by an empty space not colons.